# Nonlinear function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have forward transformations given as below:

Tx: x' = a1x + a2y + a3xy + a4.

Tx: y' = b1x + b2y + b3xy + b4.

```
function y = transformationTest (I,a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4) 
    [M N] = size(I);
    for i = 1: M
        for j = 1: N
            x1 = a1*i + a2*j + a3*i*j + a4;
            y1 = b1*i + b2*j + b3*i*j + b4;
            y(round(x1+1),round(y1+1)) = I(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

Is my implementation wrong or what because I am getting to large images and meaningless.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by large images and meaningless. Could you please clarify?

Comment: depends in the numbers, that you decided to not share. Please read [ask] and [mcve] so you can get better help

Comment: I assume this `...*i*j`, leading to `*MN` is causing x1 and y1 to grow much larger than you expected. I guess what you have to do here is to do `i = (1:M)/M`, and likewise for `j`.
But until you give numbers and expected output, I cannot help further.